# Ask for text, pass to terminal, in Automator

Tags: automator, metadata

I am trying to create a simple Automator service to quickly change metadata on photos. I would like to be able to select x amount of files, run the service, and get a popup that asks for the f-number I want to change to:

At the moment this is set up to grab selected files in finder, and run the following terminal command:

```
exiftool -FNumber="1.8" -overwrite_original_in_place "$@"
```

[image]

(exiftool us an application used to edit metadata)

This command works, but the FNumber is hardcoded to 1.8. I would like to be able to dynamically specify the f-number via the "Ask for text" command. However, I don't know how I can ask for text and use the selected files as inputs at the same time. Does anyo

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, I was working on doing the same thing as @Daniel.

But I was trying to only pass the exiftool command  once. So now you have a choice :-).

```
  property ExifTool : "PathTo/exiftool -FNumber="
property ExifToolOption : "-FNumber="
on run {input, parameters}
    set pathList to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to count of items of input
        set this_item to item i of input
        set pathList to pathList & space & "\"" & (POSIX path of this_item) & "\"" as string

    end repeat
    display dialog "Enter FNumber" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
    set fStop to text returned of the result
    set fStop to fStop as number
    do shell script ExifTool & space & ExifToolOption & fStop & space & "-overwrite_original_in_place" & space & pathList
end run
```

Comment: How would you do that not using AppleScript, just using quick action - shell script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not particularly bound to using Automator's "Ask for text" command, you could do this:

In your service, have the action item be "Run AppleScript" rather than "Run Shell Script"

Use this AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myvar to text returned of (display dialog "What F-stop do you want to set?" default answer "1.8")
    repeat with myitem in input
        set myscript to "exiftool -FNumber=\"" & myvar & "\" -overwrite_original_in_place \"" & (POSIX path of myitem) & "\""
        do shell script myscript
    end repeat
end run
```

[image]